# Firefox doesn't affected with JavaScript changes

Tags: javascript, firefox

I updated a JavaScript file then uploaded it to my server. The changes was effective on all browsers except Firefox. Firefox see the old version file which returns an error. I opened the file on the web console and still the same old version of the file. I also tried the clear refresh with no success.

I hope any body can help to fix this problem

Comment: have you tried refreshing history?

Comment: Do you mean clear history?

Comment: Not the history, it's the cache https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache

Comment: This sounds much like a trivial user problem or it is lacking vital information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your cache. For example, if you're using windows, press CTRL+R or CTRL+F5.

Alternatively, for testing, you can do something like this with PHP:

```
<script src="js/barfoo.js?v=<?=rand(1,99999);?>"></script>
```

(...which is, by the way, especially nice if used with favicons!)

Comment: Did you actually replace the old version? If so, it probably *is* the cache. If not, did you check the src-attribute of your script tag?